# Activity class not found even though the class appears in dex disassembly

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, dex

I'm developing an Android app (let's call it *AppName*) in Unity 2017.3 Beta 1. I need a custom Activity to run some Java code on Startup. I have the code for the `AppNameActivity` in a separate project which uses `gradle` to package the Activity into the `AppName.jar` file which is then dropped into Unity's `AppName/Assets/Plugins/Android` folder, along with a custom `AndroidManifest.xml` which referencet it. I uses Unity's *Build and Run* feature (Build System: Gradle, Development Build).

When I start the app on my Android device, it crashes instantly. It seems as if the Activity class was missing, but on closer inspection, it is actually there.

Via `adb logcat` I can obtain this error:

```
V/ActivityThread(24831): Handling launch of ActivityRecord{2609126c token=android.os.BinderProxy@2101f035 {de.companyname.appname.rebuild/de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity}}
D/OpenGLRenderer(23986): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(23986): Flushing caches (mode 0)
I/art     (24831): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity>
D/AndroidRuntime(24831): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(24831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(24831): Process: de.companyname.appname.rebuild, PID: 24831
E/AndroidRuntime(24831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.companyname.appname.rebuild/de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.companyname.appname.rebuild-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.companyname.appname.rebuild-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5562)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at java{de.companyname.appname.rebuild/de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity}.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.companyname.appname.rebuild-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.companyname.appname.rebuild-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1070)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2371)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        ... 14 more
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):        ... 13 more
E/AndroidRuntime(24831):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

The relevant part of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:isGame="false" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection" android:name="de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    (...)
  </application>
```

Here's the output of `dexdump`, executed on the Android device via `adb shell` with the argument `/data/app/de.companyname.appname.rebuild-2/base.apk`.

```
Processing './base.apk'...
Opened './base.apk', DEX version '035'
(...)
Class #69            -
  Class descriptor  : 'Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity;'
  Access flags      : 0x0001 (PUBLIC)
  Superclass        : 'Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/UnityPlayerActivity;'
  Interfaces        -
  Static fields     -
    #0              : (in Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity;)
      name          : 'ACTION_USB_PERMISSION'
      type          : 'Ljava/lang/String;'
      access        : 0x001a (PRIVATE STATIC FINAL)
    #1              : (in Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity;)
      name          : 'TAG'
      type          : 'Ljava/lang/String;'
      access        : 0x001a (PRIVATE STATIC FINAL)
  Instance fields   -
    #0              : (in Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity;)
      name          : 'mUsbManager'
      type          : 'Landroid/hardware/usb/UsbManager;'
      access        : 0x0002 (PRIVATE)
    #1              : (in Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity;)
      name          : 'mUsbReceiver'
      type          : 'Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;'
      access        : 0x0012 (PRIVATE FINAL)
    #2              : (in Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity;)
      name          : 'validProductNames'
      type          : 'Ljava/util/Collection;'
      access        : 0x0002 (PRIVATE)
  Direct methods    -
    #0              : (in Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity;)
      name          : '<init>'
      type          : '()V'
      access        : 0x10001 (PUBLIC CONSTRUCTOR)
      code          -
      registers     : 4
      ins           : 1
      outs          : 2
      insns size    : 32 16-bit code units
      catches       : (none)
      positions     : 
        0x0000 line=27
        0x0003 line=22
        0x000a line=25
        0x0018 line=28
        0x001f line=29
      locals        : 
        0x0000 - 0x0020 reg=3 this Lde/companyname/appname/rebuild/AppNameActivity; 
(...)
```

I also used the tool `AndroidSdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer dex packages ~/src/appname/UnityExport.apk` to get a disassembly on my dev machin, which yields:

```
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
P d 465 944 66105   <TOTAL>
P d 420 454 49362   com
(...)
C d 8   10  1067    de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity
M d 1   1   119     de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity <init>()
(...)
```

So I'm rather sure that the class `de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity` is present on the device.

**Update:**
I was worried about the package being mentioned twice in a row in the error log: `{de.companyname.appname.rebuild/de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity}` so I changed the value in the manifest from `android:name="de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity"` to `android:name=".AppNameActivity"`. Still, I get *exactly* the same error message.

Comment: Is this the debug build generated by android studio? Try generating the build via `Build -> Generate Signed APK...` and install that `debug` or `release` build. Are you getting the same error even then?

Comment: I used the gradle build feature in Unity3d when I experienced that problem. I also tried to export a gradle project from Unity3d which I can build by manually running gradle. When I do this, I run into other problems at runtime which seem unrelated to this problem. I'm currently trying to understand what's going on there.

Comment: I didn't try Android Studio yet - as far as I know, I will run gradle under the hood anyway, so I expect the same error there which I am currently investigating. Anyway, I'll try Android Studio as soon as I am done with my current experiments.

Comment: This problem occurs when `InstantRun` is enabled in Android Studio and you try to manually install the generated debug build. But i am not sure about the Unity build pipeline.

Comment: That's an interesting hint. Though I do not currently use Android Studio, it's rather likely that my build.gradle file(s) contain some bits that were generated or modified by Android Studio. I'll take a look at this.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Henry. Even though InstantRun was not the problem, your idea lead me to the solution (see the Answer below) because I switched from debug build to release build, which was the most straight-forward way to make sure that InstantRun is really off.

Comment: Awesome. When it comes to build, release build is the source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem: I was missing a superclass.

When I tried to make a *release build* (before, I always tried the *debug build*), I got several error messages, including this line:

`Warning: de.companyname.appname.rebuild.AppNameActivity: can't find superclass or interface de.companyname.appname.rebuild.UnityPlayerActivity`

In fact, I had made a mistake while bundling `AppName.jar`, so that the superclass was missing. I'm still surprised about the rather unspecific runtime error from the AndroidRuntime which only mentioned `AppNameActivity`.

I rebuilt the `jar` and the *release build* and now this error is fixed, `AppNameActivity` is loaded and it's constructor executed (and then crashes during execution due to some other problems which are beyond the scope).

For a moment, I was still unsure about this whole thing because I looked at the *old* output of `dexdump` (which I quoted partially in my question) which confirmed the presence of `UnityPlayerActivity`. Upon closer inspection, I noticed that `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity` was included, but the actual superclass was `de.companyname.appname.rebuild.UnityPlayerActivity`